# Brainstorming sites

Tags: technique, brainstorming

So, I'm pretty new to all this online writing media! Since I've found it I have so many questions needing answers.

Main Question

> Are there any sites that can be able to hold ideas and drafts for ideas, or sites that have any sort of great brainstorming technique.

I really would like to find one. I have to find a great way to brainstorm a new idea... (I would like the site to be free)

Thanks 
  -A.N.M.

Comment: I don't understand what you're really searching for. A website where different users can gather to brainstorm altogether? Or a website where you can pitch your ideas and ask for feedback?

Comment: No, where just one person can brainstorm.

Comment: Some writers find that a good notebook is a wonderful place to brainstorm and store your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Xmind?

Xmind is a great tool for mind maps and brainstorming, I love this tool it has a desktop, mobile and web based versions all synced in the cloud.

http://www.xmind.net/

Answer (score 0):

There are many peer-review sites, however, most writers fear sharing ideas because they can be stolen. Ideas cannot be copyrighted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any brainstorming sites where authors just sit down and talk with one another to help each other look for plot-holes, or help expand on ideas or anything. But I know that sometimes having a visual on timelines and stuff when I plan really help me. So here are two websites that help with making timelines:

1) https://www.tiki-toki.com

2) https://www.storylinecreator.com

These really helped me. The Storylinecreator was more visual, and the tiki-toki was helpful for planning out and solidifying dates and such since it actually keeps track of dates, times, etc.